# What is the most mundane & intuitive meaning of the radical of a finite group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I am asking this question because I am trying to solve this problem from a class note:

> Assume that $R(G)$ is simple and not commutative, show that $G$ is a subgroup of $Aut(R(G)).$

The note's definition of $R(G)$ is not easy to digest, it consists of chains upon chains of sub-definitions like these:

(1) $R(G) = E(G)F(G)$; 
(2) Where $F(G)$ is defined to be the (complex) product of all subgroups $O_p(G)$ with $p$ a prime number, this group $F(G)$ is called the *Fitting* subgroup of $G$; 
(3) And $E(G)$ is defined to be the subgroup of $G$ generated by all *components* of $G$, this group $E(G)$ is called the *Layer* of $G$. And then another chain of definitions: A subnormal subgroup of $G$ is called a *component* of $G$ if it is *quasisimple*; the group $G$ is called *quasisimple* if $G’ = G$ and $G/Z(G)$ is simple.

Is it possible to take a break from formalism for just a little while and let me understand $R(G)$ in the most mundane and intuitive way? Thank you for your time and help.

PS. This chapter on Radical of Group is given *before* the next one on Solvable Group, so I assume the explanation does not involve solvability.

Comment: Hint for your question, $C_G(R(G))\leq R(G)$.

Comment: $R(G)$ is the generelization of the fitting subgroup $F(G)$ acording to M.Isaacs.

Comment: I have neve rcome across this terminology before. This subgroup is usually called the *generalized Fitting subgroup*, and is denoted by $F^*(G)$. The definition evolved as a result of attempts to find a uniform method of defining a subgroup of a finite group $G$ that is contained in its own centralizer. For solvable groups, the Fitting subgroup has this property. This subgroup arises a lot in the classification of finite simple groups, but the arguments involved are very technical, and I am doubtful whetehr it is possible to understand this topic in any general non-technical fashion.